# Remote Neo4j getting slow over time in Java-Tinkerpop3-Bolt setup

Tags: java, performance, neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop3

We're running into performance problems while running a `Neo4j` database on one server, and using it from a different server within the same network. The main problem is, while running the same integration tests periodically, they become **slower over time**.

Our current setup is:

- `Tinkerpop3` graph API (Java) on server 1, using `neo4j-gremlin-bolt` to use this API with a **remote** `Neo4j` server via `Bolt` protocol
- Server 2 running `Neo4j` 3.0.4

In Java on server 1, we have integration tests with these imports:

```
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase;
import com.steelbridgelabs.oss.neo4j.structure.Neo4JGraph;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph;
```

And code similar to:

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(...);
public void clearGraph() {
    Graph graph = new Neo4jGraph(driver,...);
    try (Transaction transaction = graph.tx()) {
        // Query/add/delete data in the graph.
        transaction.commit();
    }
    graph.close();
}
```

Although our test periodically removes all nodes and relations from the `Neo4j` database, we observe performance problems.

1. **Continuous database size growth**: the nodestore.db and relationshipstore.db do still grow even after removing all nodes. This issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761126/neo4j-database-size-grows). I couldn't solve this yet, but it's **not crucial** at the moment.
2. A **critical issue** then is the fact that our test **gets slower over time**. Apparently, `Bolt` itself has way higher latency compared to the `HTTP` client as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050715/neo4j-over-bolt-protocol-has-very-high-latency). However, does not explain the **constant slowing** we have to deal with. None of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620807/neo4j-getting-slow-stuck-on-amazon-ec2) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507239/neo4j-get-pretty-slower-with-high-transaction-concurrency) helped, and neither using [store-utils](https://github.com/jexp/store-utils) nor [removing the whole graph directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4507812/7720909) are reasonable options for a planned live system.

My central question is: **Did we do a logical mistake setting up our Java-Neo4j connection, or is there a crucial performance issue with Neo4j?** (since I found the mentioned similar posts)